# Hazelcast + Spring(xml config) + hz map store error

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Using hazelcast 3.8.2 (hazelcast-all jar) + IMap+ mapstore + Spring 4.3.8 (xml config).  In Spring xml config, 'hz:map-store' throws an error saying:

```
17:49:40.519 ERROR [main] org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager – Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1868ed54] to prepare test instance [com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.dataaccess.maps.EntitlementMapTest@1b9ea3e3] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'hz:map' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
                http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring.xsd">



   <hz:hazelcast id="hzInstance1">
      <hz:config>
        ...
      </hz:config>
   </hz:hazelcast>

   <hz:client id="hzInstance1Client">
    ...
   </hz:client>

   <hz:map id="entitlementCache" instance-ref="hzInstance1" name="entitlement">
      <hz:map-store enabled="true" implementation="linearEntitlementMapStore"
                    write-delay-seconds="30000"/>

   </hz:map>

   <bean id="linearEntitlementMapStore" class="com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.dataaccess.maps.LinearEntitlementMapStore" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure MapStore in `<hz:config>` section.

Correct config should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring.xsd">

<hz:hazelcast id="hzInstance1">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:map name="entitlement">
            <hz:map-store enabled="true" implementation="linearEntitlementMapStore"
                          write-delay-seconds="30000"/>
            <!-- ... -->
        </hz:map>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>

<hz:client id="hzInstance1Client">
    <!--... -->
</hz:client>

<bean id="linearEntitlementMapStore" class="com.twc.ctg.ecp.service.dataaccess.maps.LinearEntitlementMapStore"/>
```